# How to download large files from aws s3 with restart on network loss

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-nodejs, node-streams

I am trying to implement a "network safe" downloader from aws s3 bucket.
the downloader should be able to download a single .zip file from s3 and write it to a local .zip file.

My current approach is using node with readStream and writeStream ass follows

```
const download = async () => {
    AWS.config.update(
        {
            accessKeyId: "",
            secretAccessKey: "",
            region: ""
        }
    );

    const s3 = new AWS.S3();

    const params = {
        Bucket: '',
        Key: ''
    };

    const { ContentLength: contentLength } = await s3.headObject(params).promise();

    const rs = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream()
    const ws = fs.createWriteStream(path.join('./', 'file.zip'));

    let progress = 0;

    rs.on('data', function (chunk) {
        progress += chunk.length;
        console.log(`Progress: ${progress / contentLength * 100}%`);
    });

    rs.pipe(ws);
}
```

what i need is a way to catch/create an event regarding network errors that will allow me to pause and restart the download when network is back on.
or even better - auto restart the download when network is restored.
currently i couldn't find any events regarding network errors and seems that network loss while download is in process does not triggers the 'error' event.

any solutions in node/python will be very appriciated

Comment: You could build a downloader that fetches multiple chunks of the S3 object using the ranged GET feature. For example, query the size of the object in advance and then performed multiple 10MB ranged GETs, storing each chunk locally along with some metadata indicating progress, and build some simple retry logic for a failed chunk or network connection issue.

Answer (score 0):

Short update: found a work around using wget to download a preSignedUrl to the object i want to download. still not the native experience i wanted to have. share your thoughts

```
export class Downloader {
    constructor(dest_dir, file_name_to_save) {
        this.dest_dir = dest_dir;
        this.file_name = file_name_to_save;
        this.progress = "61%"
    }

    async download_file(on_progress, on_done, socket, io) {

        let client = new S3Client({
            region: 'eu-west-1',
            credentials: {
                accessKeyId: "",
                secretAccessKey: "",
            }
        });

        const command = new GetObjectCommand({ Bucket: "s", Key: "" });
        const url = await getSignedUrl(client, command, { expiresIn: 3600 });



        let child = spawn('wget', ['-c', '-O', this.dest_dir + this.file_name, url]);

        socket.on('cancel', () => {
            child.kill()
            console.log("killed child")
        })

        child.stderr.on('data', (e) => {
            let stdout = e.toString();

            let p = stdout.match(/([0-9]+?\%)+/g);

            if (p && p.length > 0 && p[0] != this.progress) {
                on_progress && on_progress(p[0])
                console.log(p[0])
                this.progress = p[0]
            }
        });


        child.stdout.on('end', function (data) {
            on_done && on_done("end");
            console.log("end: ", data)
            child.kill();
        });

        child.on('exit', function (code) {
            if (code != 0) console.log('Failed: ' + code);
            else console.log("success!", code)

            on_done && on_done("exit");
        });
    }
}
```